# Manage a list of Constants

Tags: c#

In several projects, we have a list of constant values in the database.  These each have a table, name, and a GUID value.  For example a Ticket Status table might have 3 values, "Open", "Closed" and "Hold".  In our C# code a framework generates a C# file, as follows.

```
public class TicketStatus { 
     public static Guid Open =  new Guid( "7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a");
     public static Guid Closed =  new Guid( "41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628");
     public static Guid Hold =  new Guid( "41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8");
}; // end of TicketStatus
```

This allows us to write some clean(ish) code that sets ticket status as follows
ticket.strStatus = TicketStatus.Open.ToString();

While this works:
- It produces pretty clean C# code that's easy to ready and maintain
- It's supported by Intellisense

it's still clumsy, in that
- We have to continually convert to string for many operations
- The use of GUIDs seems like overkill.
- We cannot write a "normal" switch statement

```
// This won't compile
        switch( strStatus ) {
        case TicketStatus.Open:
        case TicketStatus.Closed:
        // do some stuff.
        break;
        }
```

The code was originally implemented with a bunch of GUIDs, to manage the case when a database would return the values in all upper case.

The question: What's the best way to code these constant values, so that it supports IntelliSense and switch statements?

Comment: Why not use a string?

Comment: Does `Guid.ToString()` return the GUID value that you use to instantiate a GUID instance?

Comment: `switch (new Guid(strStatus)) { ... }`?

Comment: Is `strStatus` intended to be a `Guid` or Open/Close/etc.?

Comment: See the string solution below.  I ran into compile errors originally, and I think the db was returning the GUIDs in upper case.  I'll proceed using the string solution, and fix in uppper/lower in my db interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Kirk,
Here's the string solution that I'm using.

```
public static class TicketStatus {
    public const string Open = "7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a";
    public const string Closed = "41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628";
    public const string Hold = "41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8";
}; // end of TicketStatus

string strTemp = TicketStatus.Open;
switch (strTemp) {
    case TicketStatus.Open:
        strTemp = "Jackpot";
        break;
}
```

Comment: This looks quite logical. Why not continue using it?

Comment: Yes, I'm ditching the GUIDs from my original code, I'm only using them as strings anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Preamble

I do really think, that you should stick to this for as long as you can.

```
public static class TicketStatus {
    public const string Open = "7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a";
    public const string Closed = "41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628";
    public const string Hold = "41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8";
}; // end of TicketStatus
```

## If you want some magic :)

There is a solution, that nobody has mentioned here. You can use attributes to assign custom values to enumerations. You need to define an attribute and some helper class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class GuidValue : Attribute
{
    public Guid Guid
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public GuidValue(Guid guid)
    {
        this.Guid = guid;
    }

    public GuidValue(string stringGuid)
    {
        this.Guid = new Guid(stringGuid);
    }
}

public static class GuidBackedEnums
{
    private static Guid GetGuid(Type type, string name)
    {
        return type.GetField(name).GetCustomAttribute<GuidValue>().Guid;
    }

    public static Guid GetGuid(Enum enumValue)
    {
        Type type = enumValue.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new Exception();
        return GetGuid(type, enumValue.ToString());
    }

    public static T CreateFromGuid<T>(Guid guid)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new Exception();
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(type))
        {
            if (guid == GetGuid(type, value.ToString()))
                return (T)value;
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in the following way:

```
enum TicketStatus
{
    [GuidValue("7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a")]
    Open,
    [GuidValue("41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628")]
    Closed,
    [GuidValue("41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8")]
    Hold
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GuidBackedEnums.CreateFromGuid<TicketStatus>(new Guid("41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628")));
        Console.WriteLine(GuidBackedEnums.GetGuid(TicketStatus.Hold));
    }
}
```

And, of course, TicketStatus is an ordinary enum. So you can use it in switch statements.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that's pretty original, but I don't really need the values as GUIDs, strings are fine.  Is there a reason to use the GUID type that I'm missing?

Comment: Don't know, really. Even if there is any reason for you to use GUIDs, it's premature to switch to them today. Because you don't know what is that reason :D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static Guid Open = new Guid("7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a");
        public static Guid Closed = new Guid("41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628");
        public static Guid Hold = new Guid("41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8");
        public enum Status1
        {
             Open,
             Close,
            Hold
        }
        public static Dictionary<Guid, Status1> Dic = new Dictionary<Guid, Status1>()
        {
            {Open , Status1.Open},
            {Closed , Status1.Close},
            {Hold , Status1.Hold}
        };
```

and then

```
var a = TicketStatus.Closed;
var label = TicketStatus.Dic.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == a).Value;
switch (label)
{
    case TicketStatus.Status1.Close:

}
```

to keep your code more readable

Comment: create enum for status, create dictionary  to store elements and then check variables. I'm sorry if my answer is not helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I would use a java-like enum and some reflection. Here's an example C# implementation. It my not work with a switch, but it will quickly identify for you the required object.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

public class TicketStatus
{
    private string _guid;

    private TicketStatus(string guid)
    {
        _guid = guid;
    }

    public string GuidValue {get {return _guid; } }

    public static readonly TicketStatus Open =  new TicketStatus("7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a");
    public static readonly TicketStatus Closed =  new TicketStatus("41f81283-57f9-4bda-a03c-f632bd4d1628");
    public static readonly TicketStatus Hold =  new TicketStatus("41bcc323-258f-4e58-95be-e995a78d2ca8");

    //Reads all static readonly fields and selects the one who has the specified GUID
    public static TicketStatus Identify(string guid)
    {
        var ticket = typeof(TicketStatus).GetFields()
                     .Where(x => (x.IsStatic == true) && (x.IsInitOnly == true) )
                     .Select(x => x.GetValue(null))
                     .SingleOrDefault(x => (x as TicketStatus).GuidValue == guid)
                     as TicketStatus;
        return ticket;

    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var guid = "7ae15a71-6514-4559-8ea6-06b9ddc7a59a";
        var ticket = TicketStatus.Identify(guid);
        if(ticket != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ticket.GuidValue + " found");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unknown ticket");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also have multiple properties for the "enum" members.

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought of the identify issue.  I'll proceed with a simple string switch to identify as needed.

Comment: You could also build a generic identify method for all your constant classes, and associate a lambda expression to each constant object of a constant class (the constructor would take a string and a lambda expression), so when a ticket type is identified you could just run the lambda.